# Get all types Belong to employee and return this type

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables which are users table, rule table, rule_requests table and rule_employee table. Find the tables below.

User table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | test1 |
| 12 | test2 |
| 13 | test3 |

Rule

| id | active |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | true |

rule requests

| rule_id | request_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Normal leave |
| 2 | Sick leave |

rule employee table

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 12 |

What i want to do is to return only user that has request normal leave and the return query must select request_type column as i need to use it in localization

i tried to use this query

```php
Employee::where('department_id', $data['department_id'])
    ->whereIn('users.id', $data['employees_ids'])
    ->whereHas('rules', function($emp) use ($data) {
        $emp->join('rule_request_type', 'rule_request_type.rule_id', 'rules.id')
            ->select('request_type_id')
            ->whereIn('request_type_id',$data['requests_ids']);
        }
    )
    ->get();
```

I had to use a subquery, so i cant retrieve the `request_type_id` match cases.

Comment: Can you provide a brief explanation of your Eloquent model relationships? It's not clear how these tables are related.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you need to use joins.

First, you need to determine the relationship between your `rules` and `employees` table. Without that, how should you be able to link the `rule_request` with the `employees` table? Something like `employee_rules`?

You can run something like this.

```
User::select("users.*")
 ->join("employees AS em", "em.user_id", "users.id")
 ->join("employee_rules AS er", "er.employee_id", "em.id")
 ->join("rules", "rules.id", "er.rule_id")
 ->join("rule_requests AS rr", "rr.rule_id", "rules.id")
 ->where("rr.request_type = 'Normal leave'")
 ->groupBy("users.id")
 ->get();
```

Since you want to return the `users`, your main table should be the user. Then you need to join it at your `employees` table. Then once you determine the link between your `rules` and `employees` table you then use it to join the two tables. Make sure to use `inner join` it will ensure you that it will only retrieve users that only have `request_type => Normal leave`.

Side note: When working with large databases, the subquery is a really bad solution. Joins are the best in that kind of scenario.

Cheers mate!